# How to write a note to the teacher?

Tags: sentence-structure

How can write a note to the teacher informing her that my child needs to leave at 2:45 ( when the second bus load of students leave) on Wednesdays instead of her regular time 2:35 pm? She needs to stay that extra time in the class because she joined a book club in school and that starts at 2:45 pm

Comment: Maybe it depends on your school district. Here in California in the public schools we would write what you wrote there - But maybe it is different in other places. Are there rules about leaving on the correct bus? I would think she could stay and go to book club - a teacher should encourage reading ...